# add div class inside php code

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have this php code

```
            <div class="form-col-2 form-text balance-width">

            <?php
                $paymentmethod=array();
                $allmethod=array('cash','repurchase', 'earning', 'commission', 'processor', 'ca:re', 'ca:ea', 'ca:co', 're:ea', 're:co', 'ea:co', 'ca:re:ea', 're:ea:co', 'ea:co:ca', 'co:ca:re', 'ca:ea:re:co');
                $methodarray=@explode(",",$revenueplans['Revenueplan']['paymentmethod']);

                $find=array('ca', 'ea', 're', 'co', ':');
                $replace=array('Cash Balance', 'Earning Balance', 'Re-purchase Balance', 'Commission Balance', ' + ');

                foreach($methodarray as $methodnm)
                {
                    if(in_array($methodnm,$allmethod))
                    {
                        if(!in_array($methodnm,array('cash','repurchase', 'earning', 'commission', 'processor')))
                            $methodnmdisp=str_replace($find, $replace, $methodnm);
                        elseif($methodnm=='processor')
                            $methodnmdisp=ucfirst($methodnm);
                        elseif($methodnm=='repurchase')
                            $methodnmdisp="Re-purchase Balance";
                        else
                            $methodnmdisp=ucfirst($methodnm)." Balance";
                        $paymentmethod[$methodnm]=__($methodnmdisp);
                    }
                }
                //$paymentmethod=array();
                //if(strpos($revenueplans['Revenueplan']['paymentmethod'],'cash') !== false)
                //  $paymentmethod['cash']=__('Cash Balance');
                //if(strpos($revenueplans['Revenueplan']['paymentmethod'],'repurchase') !== false)
                //  $paymentmethod['repurchase']=__('Re-purchase Balance');
                //if(strpos($revenueplans['Revenueplan']['paymentmethod'],'earning') !== false)
                //  $paymentmethod['earning']=__('Earning Balance');
                //if(strpos($revenueplans['Revenueplan']['paymentmethod'],'commission') !== false)
                //  $paymentmethod['commission']=__('Commission Balance');
                //if(strpos($revenueplans['Revenueplan']['paymentmethod'],'processor') !== false)
                //  $paymentmethod['processor']=__('Payment Processor');

                if($SITECONFIG['balance_type']==1)
                {
                    echo $this->Form->radio('paymentmethod', $paymentmethod, array('value'=>'cash', 'legend' => false, 'separator'=>'&nbsp;', 'onchange'=>'if(this.value=="processor") {$(".paymentprocessorfield").show(500);} else{$(".paymentprocessorfield").hide(500);} if(this.value=="processor"){processorextrafield($("#paymentprocessors").val(),processer,"'.$SITEURL.'app/processorextrafield","Revenueplan",".extrafield");showprocfee(1);}else{$(".extrafield").html("");showprocfee(0);}if(this.value.indexOf("re:")>=0 || this.value.indexOf(":re")>=0) {$(".refirstfield").show(500);} else{$(".refirstfield").hide(500);}'));
                }
                elseif($SITECONFIG['balance_type']==2)
                {
                    echo $this->Form->radio('paymentmethod',  $paymentmethod, array('value'=>'cash', 'legend' => false, 'separator'=>'&nbsp;', 'onchange'=>'if(this.value=="processor"){processorextrafield($("#paymentprocessors").val(),processer,"'.$SITEURL.'app/processorextrafield","Revenueplan",".extrafield");showprocfee(1);}else{$(".extrafield").html("");showprocfee(0);}if(this.value.indexOf("re:")>=0 || this.value.indexOf(":re")>=0) {$(".refirstfield").show(500);} else{$(".refirstfield").hide(500);}'));
                }
            ?>
            <div class="height7"></div>
        </div>
```

and this result of code (i get code result by Inspect Element in chrome)

```
<div class="form-col-2 form-text balance-width">    
            <input type="radio" name="data[Revenueplan][paymentmethod]" id="RevenueplanPaymentmethodCash" value="cash" checked="checked" onchange="if(this.value==&quot;processor&quot;){processorextrafield($(&quot;#paymentprocessors&quot;).val(),processer,&quot;https://godincome.com/app/processorextrafield&quot;,&quot;Revenueplan&quot;,&quot;.extrafield&quot;);showprocfee(1);}else{$(&quot;.extrafield&quot;).html(&quot;&quot;);showprocfee(0);}if(this.value.indexOf(&quot;re:&quot;)>=0 || this.value.indexOf(&quot;:re&quot;)>=0) {$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).show(500);} else{$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).hide(500);}" required="required">
            <label for="RevenueplanPaymentmethodCash">Cash Balance</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="data[Revenueplan][paymentmethod]" id="RevenueplanPaymentmethodRepurchase" value="repurchase" onchange="if(this.value==&quot;processor&quot;){processorextrafield($(&quot;#paymentprocessors&quot;).val(),processer,&quot;https://godincome.com/app/processorextrafield&quot;,&quot;Revenueplan&quot;,&quot;.extrafield&quot;);showprocfee(1);}else{$(&quot;.extrafield&quot;).html(&quot;&quot;);showprocfee(0);}if(this.value.indexOf(&quot;re:&quot;)>=0 || this.value.indexOf(&quot;:re&quot;)>=0) {$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).show(500);} else{$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).hide(500);}" required="required">
            <label for="RevenueplanPaymentmethodRepurchase">Re-purchase Balance</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="data[Revenueplan][paymentmethod]" id="RevenueplanPaymentmethodProcessor" value="processor" onchange="if(this.value==&quot;processor&quot;){processorextrafield($(&quot;#paymentprocessors&quot;).val(),processer,&quot;https://godincome.com/app/processorextrafield&quot;,&quot;Revenueplan&quot;,&quot;.extrafield&quot;);showprocfee(1);}else{$(&quot;.extrafield&quot;).html(&quot;&quot;);showprocfee(0);}if(this.value.indexOf(&quot;re:&quot;)>=0 || this.value.indexOf(&quot;:re&quot;)>=0) {$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).show(500);} else{$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).hide(500);}" required="required">
            <label for="RevenueplanPaymentmethodProcessor">Processor</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="data[Revenueplan][paymentmethod]" id="RevenueplanPaymentmethodCaRe" value="ca:re" onchange="if(this.value==&quot;processor&quot;){processorextrafield($(&quot;#paymentprocessors&quot;).val(),processer,&quot;https://godincome.com/app/processorextrafield&quot;,&quot;Revenueplan&quot;,&quot;.extrafield&quot;);showprocfee(1);}else{$(&quot;.extrafield&quot;).html(&quot;&quot;);showprocfee(0);}if(this.value.indexOf(&quot;re:&quot;)>=0 || this.value.indexOf(&quot;:re&quot;)>=0) {$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).show(500);} else{$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).hide(500);}" required="required">
            <label for="RevenueplanPaymentmethodCaRe">Cash Balance + Re-purchase Balance</label>    
            <div class="height7"></div>
        </div>
```

so my request is how add div and class named "PayProcessorBox" for every input and label to make like this result

(i want input and label inside one div)

```
<div class="form-col-2 form-text balance-width">    
        <div class="PayProcessorBox">
            <input type="radio" name="data[Revenueplan][paymentmethod]" id="RevenueplanPaymentmethodCash" value="cash" checked="checked" onchange="if(this.value==&quot;processor&quot;){processorextrafield($(&quot;#paymentprocessors&quot;).val(),processer,&quot;https://godincome.com/app/processorextrafield&quot;,&quot;Revenueplan&quot;,&quot;.extrafield&quot;);showprocfee(1);}else{$(&quot;.extrafield&quot;).html(&quot;&quot;);showprocfee(0);}if(this.value.indexOf(&quot;re:&quot;)>=0 || this.value.indexOf(&quot;:re&quot;)>=0) {$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).show(500);} else{$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).hide(500);}" required="required">
            <label for="RevenueplanPaymentmethodCash">Cash Balance</label>&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="PayProcessorBox">
            <input type="radio" name="data[Revenueplan][paymentmethod]" id="RevenueplanPaymentmethodRepurchase" value="repurchase" onchange="if(this.value==&quot;processor&quot;){processorextrafield($(&quot;#paymentprocessors&quot;).val(),processer,&quot;https://godincome.com/app/processorextrafield&quot;,&quot;Revenueplan&quot;,&quot;.extrafield&quot;);showprocfee(1);}else{$(&quot;.extrafield&quot;).html(&quot;&quot;);showprocfee(0);}if(this.value.indexOf(&quot;re:&quot;)>=0 || this.value.indexOf(&quot;:re&quot;)>=0) {$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).show(500);} else{$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).hide(500);}" required="required">
            <label for="RevenueplanPaymentmethodRepurchase">Re-purchase Balance</label>&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="PayProcessorBox">
            <input type="radio" name="data[Revenueplan][paymentmethod]" id="RevenueplanPaymentmethodProcessor" value="processor" onchange="if(this.value==&quot;processor&quot;){processorextrafield($(&quot;#paymentprocessors&quot;).val(),processer,&quot;https://godincome.com/app/processorextrafield&quot;,&quot;Revenueplan&quot;,&quot;.extrafield&quot;);showprocfee(1);}else{$(&quot;.extrafield&quot;).html(&quot;&quot;);showprocfee(0);}if(this.value.indexOf(&quot;re:&quot;)>=0 || this.value.indexOf(&quot;:re&quot;)>=0) {$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).show(500);} else{$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).hide(500);}" required="required">
            <label for="RevenueplanPaymentmethodProcessor">Processor</label>&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="PayProcessorBox">
            <input type="radio" name="data[Revenueplan][paymentmethod]" id="RevenueplanPaymentmethodCaRe" value="ca:re" onchange="if(this.value==&quot;processor&quot;){processorextrafield($(&quot;#paymentprocessors&quot;).val(),processer,&quot;https://godincome.com/app/processorextrafield&quot;,&quot;Revenueplan&quot;,&quot;.extrafield&quot;);showprocfee(1);}else{$(&quot;.extrafield&quot;).html(&quot;&quot;);showprocfee(0);}if(this.value.indexOf(&quot;re:&quot;)>=0 || this.value.indexOf(&quot;:re&quot;)>=0) {$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).show(500);} else{$(&quot;.refirstfield&quot;).hide(500);}" required="required">
            <label for="RevenueplanPaymentmethodCaRe">Cash Balance + Re-purchase Balance</label>    
        </div>
            <div class="height7"></div>
 </div>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dive in for loop

```
                foreach($methodarray as $methodnm)
            {
                   ?>div class="PayProcessorBox"> <?php         
                if(in_array($methodnm,$allmethod))
                {
                    if(!in_array($methodnm,array('cash','repurchase', 'earning', 'commission', 'processor')))
                        $methodnmdisp=str_replace($find, $replace, $methodnm);
                    elseif($methodnm=='processor')
                        $methodnmdisp=ucfirst($methodnm);
                    elseif($methodnm=='repurchase')
                        $methodnmdisp="Re-purchase Balance";
                    else
                        $methodnmdisp=ucfirst($methodnm)." Balance";
                    $paymentmethod[$methodnm]=__($methodnmdisp);
                }
                              ?></div><?php
            }
```

Comment: i try it and give me error "An Internal Error Has Occurred."
and i try make like this 
`echo "<div class=\"PayProcessorBox\">";`
and 
`echo "</div>";`

but get like this result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECQid.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you just have to echo a couple more lines like this:

```
echo "<div class=\"PayProcessorBox\">"; // add this line

if($SITECONFIG['balance_type']==1)
                {
                    echo $this->Form->radio('paymentmethod', $paymentmethod, array('value'=>'cash', 'legend' => false, 'separator'=>'&nbsp;', 'onchange'=>'if(this.value=="processor") {$(".paymentprocessorfield").show(500);} else{$(".paymentprocessorfield").hide(500);} if(this.value=="processor"){processorextrafield($("#paymentprocessors").val(),processer,"'.$SITEURL.'app/processorextrafield","Revenueplan",".extrafield");showprocfee(1);}else{$(".extrafield").html("");showprocfee(0);}if(this.value.indexOf("re:")>=0 || this.value.indexOf(":re")>=0) {$(".refirstfield").show(500);} else{$(".refirstfield").hide(500);}'));
                }
                elseif($SITECONFIG['balance_type']==2)
                {
                    echo $this->Form->radio('paymentmethod',  $paymentmethod, array('value'=>'cash', 'legend' => false, 'separator'=>'&nbsp;', 'onchange'=>'if(this.value=="processor"){processorextrafield($("#paymentprocessors").val(),processer,"'.$SITEURL.'app/processorextrafield","Revenueplan",".extrafield");showprocfee(1);}else{$(".extrafield").html("");showprocfee(0);}if(this.value.indexOf("re:")>=0 || this.value.indexOf(":re")>=0) {$(".refirstfield").show(500);} else{$(".refirstfield").hide(500);}'));
                }

echo "</div>"; // add this line
```

Comment: i test it but give me one div and class for all input and label
see screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqF48.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Well, then you'll need to add this to the start and end of the loop where it is actually echo'ed:

```
?> <div class="PayProcessorBox"> <?php
// ... php display code displaying each input and label
?> </div> <?php
```

Kind of a cheat to leave php coe, but it works 100%.

Comment: not work sir give me error "An Internal Error Has Occurred"

Comment: try `<?` not `<?php`

Comment: you mean like this ?
<?php <div class="PayProcessorBox"> ?>
or
<? <div class="PayProcessorBox"> ?>

Comment: Neither, `?>` is the exit tag or php, the html should be outside of php `?> <div class="PayProcessorBox"> <?php`

Comment: i'm added your code but give me one div and class for all input and label like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqF48.jpg

Comment: put it inside the `foreach` loop, just after the first `{` and right before the last `}`

Comment: i do it look
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlH9F.jpg
but same problem give me one div and class for all inputs and labels
i don't know what problem